# Где и почему используют explained_variance_score()

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Хотелось бы узнать почему метрика explained_variance_score() рабочая? В каким моделях машинного обучения использовать в каких лучше избегать использование? Какие граничные случаи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эту метрику можно использовать [в задачах регрессии](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#regression-metrics) (например: [Linear Regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), [SVR](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html), etc.).

[Explained variance is routinely used in principal component analysis. The relation to the Fraser–Kent information gain remains to be clarified.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_variation#In_principal_component_analysis)

As the fraction of "explained variance" equals the squared correlation coefficient R<sup>2</sup>, it shares all the disadvantages of the latter: it reflects not only the quality of the regression, but also the distribution of the independent (conditioning) variables.

[Недостатки](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explained_variation#Criticism):

> In the words of one critic: "Thus R<sup>2</sup> gives the 'percentage of variance explained' by the regression, an
>   expression that, for most social scientists, is of doubtful meaning
>   but great rhetorical value. If this number is large, the regression
>   gives a good fit, and there is little point in searching for
>   additional variables. Other regression equations on different data
>   sets are said to be less satisfactory or less powerful if their R<sup>2</sup> is lower. Nothing about R<sup>2</sup> supports these claims".[3]:58 And, after constructing an
>   example where R<sup>2</sup> is enhanced just by
>   jointly considering data from two different populations: "'Explained
>   variance' explains nothing."